# Which file prepare the style and script [ERPNEXT]

Tags: erp

i have the virtual machine for the ERPNEXT , i am trying to change the little code to meet my needs and requirements.

so i am trying to change the UI and the javascript.

for example : lets take the Desktop folder from the Apps/Home/Desktop

there are 3 files , desktop.html , desktop.css  and desktop.js

i wanted to know , which file is responsible for taking the desktop.css and desktop.js and converting them into the internal javascript and internal css

so that i can do my tweaks.

NOTE : i know that i can write the code in desktop.css and desktop.js , if i want to change the look and feel , but since i am interested in knowing which file is responsible for the conversion so that i can tweak with that module.

waiting for your favourable response.

warm regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check:

https://github.com/webnotes/wnframework/blob/master/public/js/wn/views/pageview.js

show method creates new wn.views.Page(name)

its init method uses wn.dom.eval and wn.dom.set_style to set js and css

FYI: https://github.com/webnotes/wnframework/blob/master/public/js/wn/dom.js

Comment: thanks, for that umm just a piece of advice .. please have some good comments and documentation for the code, i mean for a non python developer like me , ERPNEXT could turn out to be a worst nightmare ever.